# Transpose rows into columns at the same time as finding the nearest point of a polygon using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, cross-join-lateral

I want to create a materialized view from two tables using PostgreSQL/PostGIS. Both tables contain no NULL values.

- `schemaA.tableA`: contains the boundaries of municipalities in the form of polygons, along with their names. Attributes include: `Code | Name | Geom`
- `schemaB.tableB`: contains average meteorological measurements (temperature, precipitation, etc.) for several points for each month, as shown below:

  ```
    Point | Month | Temperature | Precipitation ...
    1210 | 1 | 3.5 | 33
    1210 | 2 | 5 | 26
    1210 | 3 | 6 | 12
    ...
    1211 | 1 | 3 | 0
    ...
  ```

Both tables have overlapping points.

My intention is to have a materialized view that contains all the municipalities (from `schemaA.tableA`) with the nearest measurement point (from `schemaB.tableB`). In addition, I'd like to have the months in columns rather than rows as at present.

With the following code it's possible to create a materialized view containing the municipalities and meteorological data of the nearest point:

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schemaB.matvue
TABLESPACE pg_default
AS select 
    row_number()  over (order by name) as id,
    a.code,
    a.name,
    a.geom,
    closest_pt."Point",
    closest_pt."Month",
    closest_pt."TEMP"
from schemaA.tableA a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT    
    b.id,
    b.geom,
    b."Point",
    b."Month",
    b."TEMP"
     FROM schemaB.tableB b
GROUP BY
    b."Point", b.id 
     ORDER BY (b.geom <-> a.geom)
   LIMIT 12) AS closest_pt
```

I'm now trying to modify my code so that I can switch the months from rows to columns. With the code below, the months switch to columns, but for each entity 11 out of 12 values are NULL. It only takes the first row corresponding to the nearest point, so it only takes one month.

```
     CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schemaB.matvue
TABLESPACE pg_default
AS select 
    row_number()  over (order by name) as id,
    a.code,
    a.name,
    a.geom,
    closest_pt."Point",
    closest_pt."TEMP_01",
    closest_pt."TEMP_02",
    closest_pt."TEMP_03",
    closest_pt."TEMP_04",
    closest_pt."TEMP_05",
    closest_pt."TEMP_06",
    closest_pt."TEMP_07",
    closest_pt."TEMP_08",
    closest_pt."TEMP_09",
    closest_pt."TEMP_10",
    closest_pt."TEMP_11",
    closest_pt."TEMP_12"
from schemaA.tableA a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT    
    b.id,
    b.geom,
    b."Point",
    MAX(b."TEMP") FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '1') AS "TEMP_01",
    MAX(b."TEMP") FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '2') AS "TEMP_02",
    MAX(b."TEMP") FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '3') AS "TEMP_03",
    MAX(b."TEMP") FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '4') AS "TEMP_04",
    MAX(b."TEMP") FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '5') AS "TEMP_05",
    MAX(b."TEMP") FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '6') AS "TEMP_06",
    MAX(b."TEMP") FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '7') AS "TEMP_07",
    MAX(b."TEMP") FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '8') AS "TEMP_08",
    MAX(b."TEMP") FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '9') AS "TEMP_09",
    MAX(b."TEMP")  FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '10') AS "TEMP_10",
    MAX(b."TEMP")  FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '11') AS "TEMP_11",
    MAX(b."TEMP") FILTER (WHERE b."Month" = '12') AS "TEMP_12"
     FROM schemaB.tableB b
GROUP BY
    b."Point", b.id 
     ORDER BY (b.geom <-> a.geom)
   LIMIT 1) AS closest_pt
```

How can I modify my code so that all the months' values are taken into account and none of the values are NULL?